# manipulating with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
$newarry =   array
            (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            )
$serial_model_itemid = array
                         (
                         [0] => 0
                         [1] => 2
                         [2] => 1
                         [3] => 2
                        )
```

need to merge both arrays and get like

```
array
         (
           [2] => 2 // in 2nd array [1]+[3] as single count
           [4] => 1 // in 2nd array [0] + [2] as  single count
         )
```

I have tried:

```
$indent_det_id1 = array_unique($data['indent_detail_id1tabl']);
$serial_model_itemid = array_count_values($data['item_id']); 
$sortted_itm_id = sort($serial_model_itemid, SORT_NUMERIC); 
$itmid_zero = array_splice($serial_model_itemid,0);
unset($itmid_zero[0]); 
$newarry = array_filter($indent_det_id1); 
$serial_model_itemid = array_count_values($data['item_id']); 
print_r( $serial_model_itemid); 
$a = array_unique( $serial_model_itemid);
```

Comment: Satish, your Question is not at all clear, update it by explaining what is the actual problem you are trying to solve and explain your example with more detail Like as why should index 0 and 2 should be added for first index in array 1

Comment: Add this code to your question.

Comment: @Arpita need $serial_model_item id array contains list of item ids and for example index 1 and 3 has same value and each index should be treated as 1 item and how if all index has same value say 10 i need a output like [2]=>10

Comment: So according to your above comment your statement `[2] => 2 // in 2nd array [1]+[3] as single count` is understandable because in second array 1 and 3rd index have value = 2, but why does  ` [4] => 1` is sum of `[0] and [2]` from second array both the indexes does not contains 4 as there value.

Comment: @ sorry if any  index has 0 it should be removed from array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // count items in array
 $serial_model_itemid = array_count_values($data['item_id']);
 // search the array
 $pos = array_search (0,$serial_model_itemid);
 // echo where it was found
 echo "0 found at ".$pos;
 // unset it
 unset($serial_model_itemid[$pos]);
 // print out for debug
 print_r($serial_model_itemid); 
 // Assign the unique key
 $a = array_unique( $serial_model_itemid);
```

Comment: Did you... just copy the OP's answer? And he accepted?

Comment: Maybe OP is creating a new account and is trying to take "credit" for his old work?

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r( $data['item_id']);


 $serial_model_itemid = array_count_values($data['item_id']);
 //$sortted_itm_id = sort($serial_model_itemid, SORT_NUMERIC);
 $pos = array_search (0,$serial_model_itemid);
 echo "0 founded at ".$pos;
 unset($serial_model_itemid[$pos]);
 print_r($serial_model_itemid);
 print_r( $serial_model_itemid);
$a = array_unique( $serial_model_itemid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `array_count_values`

```
<?php
   $n = array(0,2,1,2);
   $newarray = array_count_values($n);
   echo '<pre>'.print_r($newarray, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: print_r(array_values($newarry));//-------indent values------//
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div style = 'color:red'>";
print_r( $data['item_id']);
 $serial_model_itemid = array_count_values($data['item_id']);
 //$sortted_itm_id = sort($serial_model_itemid, SORT_NUMERIC);
 print_r( $serial_model_itemid);

Comment: Understood the logic first and then implement. Simple copy and paste will not work. The shown example will return the values as key and number of occurrence as value.

Comment: okay fine.. it was not a matter of just copying..its my own.help if any value is 0 in array need to delete both index and value and restart index

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found worked:

```
 // count items in array
 $serial_model_itemid = array_count_values($data['item_id']);
 // search the array
 $pos = array_search (0,$serial_model_itemid);
 // echo where it was found
 echo "0 found at ".$pos;
 // unset it
 unset($serial_model_itemid[$pos]);
 // print out for debug
 print_r($serial_model_itemid); 
 // Assign the unique key
 $a = array_unique( $serial_model_itemid);
```